# Touchpad stopped working after system update

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, synaptics

I'm using ubuntu 18.04.3 in my DELL VOSTRO-15 3546 laptop, after an update, suddenly my touchpad stopped working after an update 2 days ago . I'm using a USB mouse now.

`xinput list`  says

`Virtual core pointer                       id=2    [master pointer  (3)]

↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]

↳  USB OPTICAL MOUSE                        id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]

↳ **Synaptics s3203**                           id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]

⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]`

```
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

touchpad is turned on in settings. 
I tried re-installing synaptic driver but it won't work

Comment: I had the same problem. I went to Settings-System(Geräte)-Mouse and Touchpad (Maus und Tastfeld) and enabled the Touchpad there. It is now working again.

Comment: @SteveInBavaria touchpad is already enabled in system settings.

Comment: I have the exact same issue with the touchpad no longer working after an update just yesterday. Also a Dell with same version of Ubuntu (18.04.3) and Synaptics (s3203).  So far tried a few things to attempt to fix it but no luck. :( 

The update specifically included an upgrade to linux kernal version 4.15.0-72-generic. If can't find a fix I may submit a bug.

Comment: Bug has already been reported: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1854798.  Additional links in the comments here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193635/my-touchpad-has-stopped-working-in-18-04