# My touchpad has stopped working in 18.04

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

The touchpad on my laptop stopped working after the update today. The mouse cursor is visible in the corner, but it doesn't move and the click buttons don't work.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on a [Dell XPS 13 9333](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/xps-13-9333/docs). I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the [synaptics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/synaptics?tab=Newest) driver, but no joy.

Comment: The mouse cursor is visible in the corner, but it doesn't move and the click buttons don't work.

Comment: Using the older version (4.15.0-70) is a temporary workaround. Visit https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/+bugs?field.searchtext=touchpad&search=Search&field.status%3Alist=NEW&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITH_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=CONFIRMED&field.status%3Alist=TRIAGED&field.status%3Alist=INPROGRESS&field.status%3Alist=FIXCOMMITTED&field.assignee=&field.bug_reporter=&field.omit_dupes=on&field.has_patch=&field.has_no_package=&orderby=-id&start=0 and there are a lot of bugs filed on the issue.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that did the trick. Got my mouse back (and cleaned the nasty fingerprints off the screen!)

Comment: You could visit https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1854895 and mark it "Affects me too" if you have a Launchpad account.

Comment: Many of the reports involve Dell laptops.

Comment: Thanks, just did that. First I thought it was the laptop was buggy or the connection to the touchpad was loose - did manage to get a hair out of the touchpad area (and cleared a load of fluff out of the fan), so not a wasted effort!